# For-loop does not iterate to next element in a file

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a problem with my two for-loops in this code:

```
def batchm():
    searchFile = sys.argv[1] 
    namesFile = sys.argv[2] 
    writeFile = sys.argv[3] 

    countDict = {}

    with open(searchFile, "r") as nlcfile: 
        with open(namesFile, "r") as namesList: 
            with open(writeFile, "a") as wfile: 
                for name in namesList:
                    for line in nlcfile:
                        if name in line:
                            res = line.split("\t")
                            countValue = res[0]
                            countKey = res[-1]
                            countDict[countKey] = countValue
                    countDictMax = sorted(countDict, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
                    print(countDictMax)
```

The loop is iterating over this:

namesList:

Greene
Donald
Donald Duck
MacDonald

.
.
.

nlcfile:

123       1999–2000 Northampton Town F.C. season  Northampton Town
5       John Simpson Kirkpatrick
167       File talk:NewYorkRangers1940s.png       talk
234       Parshu Ram Sharma(Raj Comics)   Parshuram Sharma

.
.
.

What I get looks like this:

```
['Lyn Greene\n', 'Rydbergia grandiflora (Torrey &amp;amp; A. Gray in A. Gray) E. Greene\n', 'Tyler Greene\n', 'Ty Greene\n' ..... ]
```

and this list appears 48 times, which also happens to be the number of lines in namesList.

Desired output:

```
("string from namesList" -> "record with highest number in nlcfile")  
Greene -> Ly Greene  
Donald -> Donald Duck
```

.
.
.

I think that the two for-loops don't iterate the right way. But I have no clue, why.

Can anyone see, where the problem is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: so you want to match the names from file A to the addresses from file B? You are presenting it a bit more complicated than it is I think. Please post the desired output

Comment: Also note that `with` statements can be chained to keep the code indentation level less extreme. you can do `with open('fileA.txt', 'r') as fA, open('fileB.txt', 'r') as fB, ...` for example in a single line

Comment: It is because in your code `nlcfile`, `namesList` and `wfile` are iterators. That means, they become empty once iterated till the end. Instead you should be iterating on the `list` object as you are using it within nested `for` loop.

Comment: "Flat is better than nested."